# install4j: how can i check whether my apache tomcat server started successfully or not

Tags: java, spring, tomcat7, install4j

I've created installer using install4j, which installs tomcat as service and starts service.
Start service involves starting of my apache tomcat server (including my spring web application).

Here, i wants to perform a check whether my application in apache tomcat server got started successfully or not.

This can be checked by hitting one url of my web app, now how can i halt installer to wait till the apache tomcat gets started successfully, any Idea?

Whether this is possible using java class or not?
If yes then please give an idea.

Thanks

Satish Lakhani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a "Wait for HTTP server" action for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks Ingo Kegel,

It worked totally as expectations.
Great...
:-)

Comment: Hi Ingo,
This action checks for only 2xx response code (i need to check for 4xx also), so i can not use this actions.

For this i've written one java class, which hits url & get the response code, & i'm checking response code manually whether its 200 or 404 or any other. This works fine with linux system but for windows it does not wait for server startup. 

Is there any way i can check all error code?

Comment: The action has a "Accept all response codes" property. Does that work for you?

Comment: Right, but i wants to fail this action if response is 404 or any response rather than 200. I think if i check "Accept all responses codes" than the action will get success even if response is 404. Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Is there any way i can capture the status code of "Wait for HTTP server" action?

Comment: We'll add a property that allows you to specify a variable name for the response code in 6.1.3. Please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get a build where this is already implemented.